# trying to capture intervening sequence in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

So I am working with a Perl regex to do a basic restriction digest on DNA sequences with two enzymes.  I have a larger program that works, but it seems that I should be able to accomplish this in a few lines with a regex.  With the input DNA sequence I need to capture the enzyme cut sites, plus all the DNA in between consecutive sites.

**Input:** CATCCCCCGTCAAAAACACTTGAAAAACAT

**Enzyme 1 cut site:** CA

**Enzyme 2 cut site:** TG

**Expected Output:**

```
CATCCCCCGTCA

CAAAAACA

CACTTG

TGAAAAACA

CAT
```

I am using the following script:

```
my $input = "CATCCCTCGTCAAAAACACTTGAAAAACAT";

my $enzyme1="CA";
my $enzyme2="TG";

@cuts = $input =~ /(CA|TG[.]*CA|TG)/ig;

foreach $cut (@cuts){
    print "$cut\n";
}
```

However when I get the following:

```
CA

CA

CA

TG

CA
```

Why is my regex not capturing the both cut sites plus the intervening sequence?  I am using the parentheses for capture, but it must not be correct.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [**Positive Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) assertion for **capturing** to get overlapping matches:

```
my @cuts = ( $input =~ /(?=((?:CA|TG).*?(?:CA|TG|$)))/ig );
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/171879)

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  I haven't used that before. I'll look into it (study), but your code is perfect.  Thanks again.